# Synchronous syscalls and uninterruptible sleep

Tags: filesystems, zfs, system-calls

My application entered uninteruptible sleep. The process is stuck at `linkat`.

```
❯ sudo cat /proc/1308028/syscall
265 0xffffffffffffff9c 0x7fbd9f32a120 0xffffffffffffff9c 0x7fbd9f395930 0x400 0x7fbd9f3c1c70 0x7ffff745b7c0 0x7fbda231b1fd

❯ sudo cat /proc/1308028/stack
[<0>] cv_wait_common+0xaa/0x130 [spl]
[<0>] txg_wait_synced_impl+0xcb/0x110 [zfs]
[<0>] txg_wait_synced+0x10/0x40 [zfs]
[<0>] zfs_link+0x611/0x740 [zfs]
[<0>] zpl_link+0xa2/0x120 [zfs]
[<0>] vfs_link+0x278/0x3b0
[<0>] do_linkat+0x2f7/0x320
[<0>] __x64_sys_linkat+0x5a/0x70
[<0>] do_syscall_64+0x3e/0x90
[<0>] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x6e/0xd8
```

The root cause is likely a bad HDD, but this makes me wonder if any application should avoid synchronous IO because they all have a chance to hang forever as in this case. Or is it ZFS that is responsible to add default timeouts to all its APIs and I should use a filesystem that has timeouts everywhere?

(+ Also ,can I exit from this state without reboot?)

Comment: Where do you see a timeout?

Comment: @aviro there is no timeout, zfs deadlocks forever in mutexes until reboot

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/13427), so this looks like it is not a limitation of the kernel.

ZFS could use async implmentations and properly timeout but it's using sync implementations now.